# DBGhost settings xml

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, dbghost

I am working on a demo build server that will automate build and deployment processes. I am attempting to automate the merging of database changes to an existing database without compromising static seed data in the target database. Therefore the approach I am taking is to build the new database without the reference data only and the seed data from the target database. Then compare and sync this. The issue arises with the tool I am using DBGhost. To facilitate the merging of static data I need the agent(microsoft service) that is running the tool to check the setting "Automatically Select Tables". After speaking with tech support with Innovartis I was told there is a settings.xml file that reflects setting changes made in the GUI. However it not apparent where this is located and also how to incorporate this into an MSBuild/TeamCity automated build process. Anybody have an experience of this or does anybody have any suggestions on this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I too have been working with DB Ghost to automate database building and deployment and have found it quite powerful, but also quite cumbersome.

Anyway, with regard to the ***settings.xml*** file....if you use the GUI to perform the task you wish, selecting the relevant options along the way, the last screen gives you the options to "Create CMD line" and "Save Settings. If you chose to "Create CMD line", this will both save the options which you have seleted using the GUI, and create a .BAT file which you can run (or integrate to your build process) to automate this task.

You will be prompted for a location for where you wish to save these files.

[image: DB Ghost Final Process Review]

Answer (score 0):

I've used DBGhost on a number of projects and integrated it successfully into Continuous Build environments with TFS/Team City. Let me know what your isssues are.

The trick is to run the command based exe with the XML settings file. Then you can integrate this into any build environment and produce delta scripts/upgrade test dbs.

If you could explain exactly the problem I can detail the exact steps needed.

I've found DbGost invaluable and the single best soltuion to Db control and upgrades.